# Why is the green portion of the WiFi signal in the "Network cell info" app different between a Pixel 6 (Android 12) and a Galaxy S9 (Android 10)?

Tags: wi-fi

Google Pixel 6 (Android 12): as shown in the screenshot below, the green portion of the Wi-Fi signal goes to 55 decibel.

[image]

Samsung Galaxy S9 (Android 10): as shown in the screenshot below, the green portion of the Wi-Fi signal goes to ~63 decibel.

[image]

Why is the green portion of the Wi-Fi signal in the "Network cell info" app different between a Google Pixel 6 and a Samsung Galaxy S9?

Comment: Possibly because manufacturers can customize the value inside the ROM (I feel like I have seen a question asking about the threshold value for each bar before, but couldn't find it at the moment)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks, that makes sense. You're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Found a different but perfect dupe instead that explains both WiFi and cellular.